# How to make functions treat return value of (A | B)[] and A[] | B[] as equivalent in typescript

Tags: typescript

It seems types `(A | B)[]` and `A[] | B[]` are equivalent in TypeScript. This can be confirmed by the following:

```
var test1: number[] | string[] = [1]
var test2: (number | string)[] = ["stuff"]
var test3: (number | string)[] = test1
```

But It seems this breaks down when these types appear in return functions. This is illustrated below:

```
function getStuff(flag:number): number | string {
    if (flag == 0) {
        return 1
    } else {
        return "hello"
    }
}

function returnStuff(flag: number): number[] | string[] {
    let toReturn: (number | string)[] = [getStuff(flag)]
    // toReturn is of type (number | string)[] but trying to return it when the return type
    // is number[] | string[] fails even though they should be equivalent
    return toReturn;
}
```

I then have two questions:

1. What is the reason behind this behavior and how to fix it to get intended behavior?
2. Is there any type level machinery in TS that can be used to convert between `number[] | string[]` and `(number | string)[]`

Comment: Try to assign `['foo', 42]` to see the difference in your first sample (then the rest of the question is irrelevant, because they are different types).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What is the reason behind this behavior

> number[] | string[]

you have two possible arrays, an array that contains only number, and an array that contains only strings

```
[1,2,3,4] //valid  
["foo", "bar"] //valid  
[1,2,"foobar"] //this is invalid
```

> (number | string)[]

You have one possible array that contains either a number or string.

```
[1,2,3,4] //valid  
["foo", "bar"] //valid  
[1,2,"foobar",3,"lorem"] //valid
```

In this one, key point to remember is that, the array can contain an element that is of type string OR number, regardless if all the elements in the array is of the same type or not

## Is there any type level machinery in TS that can be used to convert between number[] | string[] and (number | string)[]

You can still use your string[] or number[] as (string | number)[]

```
let x: number[] = [1,2,3,4]

return x as (number | string)[]
```

Comment: I must mention that `x as (number | string)[]` is not a type safe conversion. It would happily accept `let x: (number|string)[] = [1, 'a']`